# Checking if Type or instance implements IEnumerable regardless of Type T

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, types

I'm doing a heavy bit of reflection in my current project, and I'm trying to provide a few helper methods just to keep everything tidy.

I'd like to provide a pair of methods to determine if a type or instance implements `IEnumerable` – regardless of the type `T`. Here is what I have at the moment:

```
public static bool IsEnumerable(this Type type)
{
    return (type is IEnumerable);
}

public static bool IsEnumerable(this object obj)
{
    return (obj as IEnumerable != null);
}
```

When I test them using

```
Debug.WriteLine("Type IEnumerable:   " + typeof(IEnumerable).IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Type IEnumerable<>: " + typeof(IEnumerable<string>).IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Type List:          " + typeof(List<string>).IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Type string:        " + typeof(string).IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Type DateTime:      " + typeof(DateTime).IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Instance List:      " + new List<string>().IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Instance string:    " + "".IsEnumerable());
Debug.WriteLine("Instance DateTime:  " + new DateTime().IsEnumerable());
```

I get this as the result:

```
Type IEnumerable:   False
Type IEnumerable<>: False
Type List:          False
Type string:        False
Type DateTime:      False
Instance List:      True
Instance string:    True
Instance DateTime:  False
```

The type method doesn't appear to work at all – I had expected a `true` for the direct `System.Collections.IEnumerable` match at least.

I'm aware that `string` is technically enumerable, albeit with a few caveats. Ideally in this case, however, I'd need the helper method to return `false` for it. I just need the instances with a defined `IEnumerable<T>` type to return `true`.

I've probably just missed something fairly obvious – can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It's clear why `typeof()` any type doesn't return `true`; you are asking whether the _type object_ implements the interface, not the type itself. Maybe you want `IsAssignableFrom()`? But in what way do you think `string` doesn't qualify? It does have "a defined `IEnumerable<T>` type".

Comment: Yep, that was the issue with the type one - I've been looking at nests of reflection jumping between types and instances all day and got more than a little confused! `string` does qualify, however in this case I do really need to rule it out - it's probably more of a matter of method naming at this stage. I think I'll just leave this as it is and add another one that just type checks on string first.

Comment: Agree with @JeroenMostert ... the "duplicate" is asking if a type is implementing `IEnumerable<x>` using reflection, this one is asking if a type is implementing `IEnumerable`, which is a different thing and requires a different solution (as proven by the different accepted answers)

Comment: Maybe you look for `ICollection<x>`instead of `IEnumerable<x>`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The following line

```
return (type is IEnumerable);
```

is asking "if an instance of `Type`, `type` is `IEnumerable`", which clearly it is not.

You want to do is:

```
return typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

Comment: @Octopoid a string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so it's true, because that's what you are asking for

Comment: @Octopoid That's the correct behavior. `string` is an `IEnumerable<char>`, which is an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Yeah, `string` does qualify, however in this case I do really need to rule it out - it's probably more of a matter of method naming at this stage. I think I'll just leave this as it is and add another one that just type checks on string first.

Comment: @Octopoid Yeah, just check if it's string first.

Comment: @Octopoid Actually it'll be more performant if you check it second!

Comment: @dav_i Good point! Very strange, not sure why, it just feels like it would be the other way until you stop and think.. at any rate - checks switched! :)

Comment: @Octopoid I had the same "oh, wait a sec" moment. Hence the double comment :)

Comment: If you are ruling out `string` for some reason, without seeing your code or knowing the requirements, you probably want to rule out many possible others too (specially if you are making a library that can be used in future code by types unknown at this point). I fail to see why `string` would be different to many other possible `IEnumerable`s. If that's the case, you'd be better off being explicit about what you support, instead of using "implementing `IEnumerable`" as a check

Comment: I don't now why this is the accepted answe. IEnumerable is not the same as IEnumerable<T> regardless of T. There can be types that only implement IEnumerable.

Comment: @Wouter It's because checking `IEnumerable` generally *accomplishes* most goals in practice. Another thing all the answers here miss is that if the ultimate goal is to see if a type is compatible with `foreach`, checking for `IEnumerable` isn't the way to go, since that's not actually what `foreach` requires: if *that's* the goal the correct way is to forget about interfaces and explicitly check for the `public X GetEnumerator()` method, and check that method's return type for a `public bool MoveNext()` method and a `public Y Current` property. Then use those to iterate.

Comment: @JasonC not for my scenario :). Good to know about foreach only needs a method not the interface. Do you know of any examples where this is actually the case?

Comment: @Wouter You can find them with https://pastebin.com/S5MkzmXK (I stuck a list of what I found there too, there's not many). Also there's `Span<T>` except it's a ref struct so you'd never encounter it generically. There's probably some other standard ref structs too that aren't easily findable. [See also](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement).

Answer (score 21):

To check if some type implements IEnumerable **regardless of T** one needs to check the GenericTypeDefinition.

```
public static bool IsIEnumerableOfT(this Type type)
{
    return type.GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.IsGenericType
           && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));
}
```

Comment: Small correction: This fails in the edge case where `type` is itself `typeof(IEnumerable<T>)`, which can give silent failures in certain situations: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vLFdHW -- the fix is easy though, just throw a `.Append(type)` right before that `.Any` so that the type itself is also checked: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5wj1KE

Comment: but... Why use IsIEnumerableOfT if you already know compile time that it is true?

Comment: You'd use it if you didn't know at compile time that it was true, e.g. an instance of some arbitrary `Type`.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to [`Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom), you can also use [`Type.GetInterfaces()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getinterfaces):

```
public static bool ImplementsInterface(this Type type, Type interfaceType)
{
    // Deal with the edge case
    if ( type == interfaceType)
        return true;

    bool implemented = type.GetInterfaces().Contains(interfaceType);
    return implemented;
}
```

That way, if you wanted to check multiple interfaces you could easily modify `ImplementsInterface` to take multiple interfaces.