# Check if type is IEnumerable and get its base type

Tags: c#

I have a property of type IEnumerable:

```
public class Model {
  public IEnumerable<Int32> values { get; set; }
}
```

On other class I have something like:

```
Type propertyType = context.getPropertyType["values"];
```

How can I check if propertyType is an IEnumerable and get its base type?

In this example the base type would be Int32.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701867/checking-if-type-or-instance-implements-ienumerable-regardless-of-type-t and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906499/getting-type-t-from-ienumerablet/17713382

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/906513/4252588