# Selecting a specific Task and its ChildTasks recursively from EF core

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have a TaskItem class that has child items of the same type:

```
public class TaskItem
{
    public Guid Id { get;set; }

    // Parent Task

    public TaskItem ParentTask { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentTaskId { get; set; }

   //Child Tasks

    public ICollection<TaskItem > ChildTasks{ get; set; }
}
```

To get a Task and its subtasks recursively as a Flat list:

```
var taskList =  taskDBContext.TaskItems.Include(c => c.ChildTasks)
                .Where(x => x.Id == taskId)
                .SelectMany(x => x.ChildTasks)
                .ToList();
```

**The issue** is that I always get a single task though the task has **many grandchildren at various levels**. My scenario is loading a specific parent and its children and grandchildren as a single list.

Also, please let me know if this is a **good design** or do I have to change it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [loading a full hierarchy from a self referencing table with EntityFramework.Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827918/loading-a-full-hierarchy-from-a-self-referencing-table-with-entityframework-core)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay No, I'm trying to load a specific parent and its children and grandchildren to the levels they are present.

Comment: Found a way to get the items recursively at: [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680957/362261)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core will not fetch data for you recursively you either need to do it yourself for every level:

```
var secondLevelx = taskDBContext.TaskItems
    .Where(x => x.Id == taskId)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildTasks)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildTasks)
    .ToList();
```

Or :

```
var secondLevelx = taskDBContext.TaskItems
    .Where(x => taskList.Select(t=>t.Id).Contains(x.Id))
    .SelectMany(x => x.ChildTasks)
    .ToList();
```

And repeat it while there are results.

Or write recursive sql query if your database supports it (for SQL Server for example you can use [CTE's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14518090/recursive-query-in-sql-server)).

**UPD**

If you are ok with making a request per level (also AFAIK that there is limit how many parameters you can pass to your query) and you don't have cycles you can do something like this:

```
var taskList = new List<TaskItem>();
var toQuery = new List<Guid> {taskId};

do
{
    var current = taskDBContext.TaskItems
        .Where(x => toQuery.Contains(x.Id))
        .SelectMany(x => x.ChildTasks)
        .ToList();
    taskList.AddRange(current);
    toQuery = current.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
} while (toQuery.Any());
```

Comment: Found a way to get the items recursively at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42680957/362261

Comment: @John yes, it basically does what i written here in recursive manner, you can do that with simple while loop also. But it still makes one request per level.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with that solution?