# How to perform a recursive function in c# using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table:

```
Column_1          Column_2
val_1              | val_14           
val_2              | val_17           
val_1              | val_2     
val_4              | null  
val_1              | val_3     
val_20             | val_4     
val_17             | null     
val_2              | val_20   
val_14             | val_6
val_14             | null
Val_6              | null
val_3              | val_30
val_3              | val_19
```

I want to display `Column_2` values

Eg: Select with `Column_1 = val_1` will return (`val_14, val_2, val_3`) from `Column_2`.

Now, I want for each values in (`val_14, val_2, val_3`) to return also values from `Column_2`.

In summary:

```
val_1 => (val_14, val_2, val_3)
val_14 => (val_6, null)
val_6 => null
val_2 => (val_17, val_20)
val_17 => null
val_20 => (val_4)
val_4 => null
val_3 => (val_30, val_19)

etc...
```

Final output (`val_14, val_2, val_3, val_6, val_17, val_20, val_4, val_30, val_19`)

I have a function, with string parameter and list of all rows data

```
public List<string> MyFunction(string value)
{
   return (from s in myListOfData where value.Contains(s.Column_1) select s).ToList();
}
```

This function return only the first level.

how can i do this query to display all children in linq? My attempts are unsuccessful.

Thank you

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19237897/11954917

Comment: Questions like this are asked daily. Please look for other questions on LINQ + hierarchy/recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is all in memory and nothing to do with an ORM.

You ***could*** use *recursion*. However, queues and stacks are safer and easier to debug.

Given some weird ill-defined *class*

```
public class Data
{
   public int? Col1 { get; set; }
   public int? Col2 { get; set; }
   public Data(int? col1, int? col2)
   {
      Col1 = col1;
      Col2 = col2;
   }
}
```

You could use an *iterator method* and a `Queue`

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRecusive(List<Data> source,int val)
{
   var q = new Queue<int>();
   q.Enqueue(val);

   while (q.Any())
   {
      var current = q.Dequeue();
      var potential = source.Where(x => x.Col1 == current && x.Col2 != null);
      foreach (var item in potential)
      {
         yield return item.Col2.Value;
         q.Enqueue(item.Col2.Value);
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
// some ill-defined test data
var list = new List<Data>()
{
   new Data(1, 14),
   new Data(2, 17),
   new Data(1, 2),
   new Data(4, null),
   new Data(1, 3),
   new Data(20, 4),
   new Data(17, null),
   new Data(2, 20),
   new Data(14, 6),
   new Data(14, null),
   new Data(6, null),
   new Data(3, 30),
   new Data(3, 19),
};

var results = GetRecusive(list,1);

// compose as a comma separated list 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",results));
```

**Output**

```
14, 2, 3, 6, 17, 20, 30, 19, 4
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SFSDiu)

---

If you like, you can turn it into an extension method to give you a *LINQ Chain Method* feel

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetRecusive(this List<Data> source, int val)
```

---

**Important Note** : If you have a *circular references* then kiss your app goodbye. This will be the same for recursion or queues. If you need to protect against this, then I suggest using a `HashSet` of visited ids

Answer (score 0):

Desired order of records is a bit-tricky to get - looks like at first you want plain 1-st level and then traverse tree in down-left direction. It's a bit tricky.
If order is not important you can:

```cs
public List<string> MyFunction(string value)
{
  return myListOfData
    .Where(x => value.Contains(x.Column_1) && x.Column2 != null)
    .Select(x => x.Column2)
    .Aggregate(new List<string>(), (t, x) => { 
      t.Add(x);
      t.AddRange(MyFunction(x));
      return t; })
    .ToList();
}
```

However, this results in lots of intermediate `List` creation. So better have enumerable:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> MyFunction(string value)
{
  foreach (var record in myListOfData.Where(x => value.Contains(x.Column_1) && x.Column2 != null)
  {
     yield return record.Column_2;
     foreach (var child in MyFunction(record.Column_2))
        yield return child;
  }
}
```

And then take ToList() of this IEnumerable.
Still, if order is important you need two functions:

```cs
public List<string> MyFunction(string value)
{
    .Where(x => value.Contains(x.Column_1) && x.Column2 != null)
    .Select(x => new Tuple<string, IEnumerable<string>>(x.Column2, Traverse(x.Column2))
    .Aggregate(new List<string>(), (t, x) => { 
      t.Add(x.Item1);
      t.AddRange(x.Item2);
      return t; })
    .ToList();
}

public IEnumerable<string> Traverse(string value)
{
  foreach (var record in myListOfData.Where(x => value.Contains(x.Column_1) && x.Column2 != null)
  {
     yield return record.Column_2;
     foreach (var child in MyFunction(record.Column_2))
        yield return child;
  }
}
```