# How to Get List<int> for all values of ParentID in another List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have 2 Lists, one is a class, the other is integers.  I am trying to return all `ParentID` values that exist in one of the Lists `Taxonomy` property, but not having any success in generating this.

For example:

```
List<int> theListingCatIDs = new List<int>();
theListingCatIDs = allMemberListings.Select(u => u.Taxonomy.ConvertAll<int>(v => v.ParentID)).Distinct().ToList();
```

This gives me error saying that it can not convert `List<List<int>>` to `List<int>`, But how can I flatten the results to just put them all in a `List<int>`??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq on a nested List - select all Id's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363730/linq-on-a-nested-list-select-all-ids)

Comment: It isn't an exact duplicate of that question, but that question and that answer will tell you how to do this.

Comment: And just by the way, you shouldn't be instantiating `theListingCatIDs` to a `List<int>` before you assign it to your LINQ expression. It's not a big deal, but that is creating an unused instance in memory that the GC then has to clean up, with no gain.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen - Thanks, I put it in the global scope of the file instead since I need to use it in an `OnItemDataBound` repeater.  Cheers :)

Comment: By the way, I have tried searching on SO before posting up this question.  Thanks for the helpful links, though, I wasn't quite sure what to search for, and the results I was getting on my searches did not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany`:

```
var ids = allMemberListings
    .SelecMany(x => x.Taxonomy)
        .Select(x => x.ParentID)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
```

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.100).aspx

It flattens the nested lists into a single list of whatever `Taxonomy` is. You can then use `Select` as normal to pull out the `ParentID`s.

Comment: Thanks!  This actually flattened the list to a list of integers, and exactly what I wanted!